# Elastic Search NEST (.net) SQL

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I am trying to use https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/xpack-sql.html
with the .net NEST client. Any ideas how? I do not really see a guide anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a couple of ways that you could write SQL and return results from Elasticsearch

#### Use the ODBC Driver

[Install the ODBC driver](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/sql-odbc.html) and use `System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection` to get records. For example

```cs
using var connection = new OdbcConnection("DSN=Local Elasticsearch");
connection.Open();

using var command = connection.CreateCommand();
command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM my_index";

using var adapter = new OdbcDataAdapter(command);
var table = new DataTable();
adapter.Fill(table);
connection.Close();

// do something with data in table
```

Note that the [ODBC driver is a platinum feature which requires a platinum or enterprise license](https://www.elastic.co/subscriptions).

#### Use the SQL API

Use the Elasticsearch SQL API, which is exposed on NEST, the .NET client. An example

```cs
var client = new ElasticClient();

var sqlResponse = client.Sql.Query(q => q
    .Query("SELECT * from my_index")
);

foreach (var c in sqlResponse.Columns)
{
    // do something with columns 
}
foreach (var r in sqlResponse.Rows)
{
    // do something with rows
}
```

The SQL API is part of the features of the default distribution.

Comment: How would one actually read  a row? I can't seem to find any documentation on it.

Comment: @SoftwarePPNV columns and rows map to the JSON response from the API: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/sql-rest-format.html#_json. `.Columns` have a name and a field type which can be used to determine how to read values in `.Rows` e.g. if the first column is a `text` datatype, then the first value in each row can be read with `r[0].As<string>()`, where `r` is the current value of enumerating over `.Rows` i.e. `foreach(var r in response.Rows) { ... }`.

Comment: The high level client always expects to deserialize a response from JSON. You could however have the API return CSV format, and use the low level client to return the response as a `StringResponse`, handling the reading of each CSV row yourself.

Comment: Is there a way to specify the format as JSON in the Elasticsearch SQL API ?

Comment: Using the REST API, you can do a POST/_sql?format=json which would return the columns and rows in JSON format. I was wondering how to specify that format using the NEST API.